# Having trouble understanding limit: $f(x,y) \to 0 $ as $ x^2 + y^2 \to \infty$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm learning multivariable calculus, here's solution to one of the problems in my book:

[image]

I'm having trouble understanding where does the $f(x,y) \to 0 $ as $ x^2 + y^2 \to \infty$ comes from?

Why the $x^2 + y^2$ term? The way I see this expression says what happens to the function as $x$ or $y$ approaches infinity, but in that case why not take absolute values instead of squares?

EDIT: I see that the function contains $x^2$ and $y^2$ terms, but the author has used same expression with other functions too. This is the first time I'm seeing limit written like this so I don't quite understand the reasoning.

Comment: The author is just saying that outside a big disc the values of $f$ are very close to zero. Hence the local maximum we found (which was strictly positive) must be a global maximum, because we needn't worry that we'd find bigger values further out on the plane; similarly for the local/global minimum.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I understand that function approaches $0$ given big enough values for $x$ and $y$. But wouldn't the standard way to write this be to approach $x$ to infinity and $y$ to infinity (or negative infinity), and seeing what happens to the function? I'm not understanding the squared terms.

Comment: You are thinking in 1-dimension twice (as it were); the author (I think) is thinking in 2-dimensions, where we usually measure distance  by $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. The danger with your way is that there are functions where $f\to 0$  on the axes, but not $f\to 0$ in general.

Comment: Substitute $x = r\cos\theta$ and $y = r\sin\theta$ and see what happens to $f$ as $r\to \infty$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I think you could expand your comments into a good answer